# LINQ ToList() Method throws FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, formatexception

The stack-trace of the exception is:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. 
at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, 
DateTimeStyles styles)
at lambda_method(Closure , **MyType** )
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

MyType is mapped to a table in DB, which has column of type date.

[image]

Now, in my code I have the following method:

```
private static List<T> MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> results)
    {
        if (results == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var filteredResults = results.AsQueryable();
        return filteredResults.ToList();
    }
```

The exception occurs on line: return filteredResults.ToList();

The format which is saved in DB is: 2016-12-14
(YYYY-MM-DD).
I understand (from reading other threads regarding this issue) that the problem might be related to the server's culture or time/date settings. Yet, I haven't succeeded in reproducing this exception. Do you have any suggestions on how to reproduce or prevent this issue?

Comment: If you don't show where you create `results` we can't help to fix it. The exception is raised at `ToList` because that is where you execute the query. **Why don't you store datetimes as datetime in the database**?

Comment: results contains the items from DB without any manipulation. Why does it matter Whether or not I save the datetimes as datetime instead of date? In Debug (in C# code), I can see that the entity contains a valid property of datetime. Do you think this is what causes the issue?

Comment: Well, somewhere must be code that uses `DateTime.Parse` or `System.Convert.ToDateTime`. That means you have a string and whant to parse it to DateTime. That raises the question why it isn't a `datetime` in the db in the first place or - if it's stored as datetime - why you convert it to string before you again parse it to `DateTime`.

Comment: I don't think I have a code that uses DateTime.Parse or System.Convert.ToDateTime. Why does the exception occurs on LINQ.TOLIST() and not the parse or convert.ToDateTime lines (if I indeed had these lines)?

Comment: The LINQ expression you are passing as `results` is only evaluated when you enumerate it, in your case when you call `ToList()`. The stacktrace shows that `results` uses  `Parse` somewhere inside a `Where` clause.

Comment: You were right: there was a predicate (string) that includes dynamic linq in it - (contains the parse method ). Write your answer separately, and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In these scenarios it can sometimes help to add an extra string property in your type to avoid data binding problems. Then you can write the database value to that string field, and then convert it to DateTime in another field in a controlled manner.

```
public class PocoObject
{
    public string DateString { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime date;
            return DateTime.TryParseExact(DateString, 
                "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                DateTimeStyles.None, 
                out date) 
            ? date : DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```